# Handle Ajax request and response zend framework

Tags: ajax, json, zend-framework

I want to send Ajax request to controller, I make like this in the client side

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "public/visits/visit/get-visits",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data)
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("fail :(");
    }
});
```

at the server side I handle the request as other requests

```
public function getVisitsAction() {
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $mapper = new Visits_Model_VisitsMapper();
    $allVisits = $mapper->getAllVisits();
    echo json_encode($allVisits);
 }
```

When I call the action, fail alert occurs and when I check it out through fire bug I found that it  returns the json data to client side to page get-visit.phtml.

How can I handle the response in the success function from the page that send the json request and redirecting it to get-visit.phtml page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Zend has Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Json which do these actions:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
echo json_encode($allVisits);
exit;
```

So it could be even simpler:

```
public function getVisitsActions() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $mapper = new Visits_Model_VisitsMapper();

            $this->_helper->json($mapper->getAllVisits());
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Not Ajax';
        // ... Do normal controller logic here (To catch non ajax calls to the script)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a more correct way of doing this. I would use the following in your controller

```
public function getVisitsActions() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if ($this->getRequest()-isPost()) {

            $mapper = new Visits_Model_VisitsMapper();
            $allVisits = $mapper->getAllVisits();

            $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
            echo json_encode($allVisits);
            exit;
        }
    }
    else {
        // ... Do normal controller logic here (To catch non ajax calls to the script)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

//client side

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "public/visits/visit/get-visits",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
           alert(data[i]);
       }
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("fail :(");
    }
});
```

//server side

```
public function getVisitsAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $mapper = new Visits_Model_VisitsMapper();
        $allVisits = $mapper->getAllVisits();
        echo json_encode($allVisits);
        exit;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Zend while using Zend json you don't need to further parse the data in ajax portion . Zend does it on its own.
Further in response header: `Content-Type:application/json`

*server side* :

```
$this->_helper->json($data);
```

*client side* :

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "public/path to",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
      var username = data.user_name;
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to disable the view rendering for your action in case it's being called with the `POST` HTTP method. Here's how I do it:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('noViewRenderer', true);
```

There are other ways to do it, though. You can see more information in the official [ViewRenderer documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonModel - simply return:

> return new JsonModel();

Don't forget to add

> use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "public/path to",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
           alert(data[i]);
       }
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("fail :("");
    }
});
```